# How to find out which commit went first?

Tags: git, git-log

**Having two commits SHA1, how do I get which went first without *manually* analyzing the git log?**

*Note that I am not trying to find which one is the ancestor of the another, I want to know which one was pushed first.*

I want to get it by it's chronological order in the git history, not by the commit date. Any method is welcome but a straight forward way is preferred (I am using it directly on my terminal emulator, not on a script).

---

I tried using `git merge-base` as @wRAR suggested.

First off, there is a drawback: `git merge-base --is-ancestor` doesn't give me output. It exits with 0 or 1 without outputing anything to stdout. Its ok when scripting, but when *manually* using it directly on my terminal I have to check the exit status in a extra step afterwards (`echo $?`on bash, `$LASTEXITCODE`on PowerShell). Not a deal breaker, but generates a little hassle.

But, anyway, it didn't work.

Works in the following scenario:

```
> git log --oneline --graph
| * <SHA1 D> Fourth commit.
| * <SHA1 C> Third commit.
| * <SHA1 B> Second commit.
| * <SHA1 A> First commit.
> git merge-base --is-ancestor <SHA1 B> <SHA1 C>
> echo $?
0
> git merge-base --is-ancestor <SHA1 C> <SHA1 B>
> echo $?
1
```

But not in this one (doesn't do what I intend):

```
> git log --oneline --graph
*   <SHA1 D> Merged work.
|\
| * <SHA1 C> Paul's first commit.
* | <SHA1 B> John's second commit.
|/
* <SHA1 A> John's first commit.
> git merge-base --is-ancestor <SHA1 B> <SHA1 C>
> echo $?
1
> git merge-base --is-ancestor <SHA1 C> <SHA1 B>
1
```

Comment: It works as intended: neither of commits is another one's ancestor.

Comment: If you want to use something else than the natural commit DAG to establish a commit ordering please clarify that.

Comment: @wRAR Added a note clarifying what I intend.

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the commit date of both commits. It can be seen in `git show` (or in any other suitable command) with `--format=fuller` or with a custom format including the commit date field.

Answer (score 0):

The only order `git` knows about is the one given by the ancestor relationship. Commit times, etc depend on the (possibly going with the moon) clock of the machine where the commiting is done, could be the original commit instant of a commit that was since amended/edited several times, and could even be totally fake.